# Confusions about notations in Durrett’s Probability Theory and Examples( 5th edition)

Tags: probability-theory, notation

[image]

The two notations highlighted above are **not defined** before. I have browse through all pages before to ensure this. I tried to find out their definitions in the context but failed.

Do these notations too common to be referred to especially? But I have never encountered them at least in Kai Lai Chung’s A Course in Probability Theory.

Thank you for any answers or comments! I have been stuck for a long time.

ps. These notations also appear in the 4th edition of the book, but are not defined not.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}_\mu$ is defined in that remark.  $P_\mu$ is defined, albeit indirectly, in the fourth edition at the beginning of the chapter on Markov chains (if you have access to it, it's the first half of page 275)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard interpretation of the notation $P_x$ and $\mathbb E_x$ in the context of Markov chains is that they are probabilities and expected values under the assumption that the starting state is $x$. This seems to be consistent with how they're used here. (Note that $P_x$ and $\mathbb E_x$ should be interpreted as special cases of $P_\mu$ and $\mathbb E_\mu$.)

So, for example, in $$P_x(X_{m+n}=z) = \sum_y P_x(X_m = y) P_y(X_n = z)$$ we interpret $P_x(X_{m+n}=z)$ as the probability that $X_{m+n}=z$ when the Markov chain is initialized at $X_0 = x$. (I wouldn't want to call this a conditional probability $P(X_{m+n}=z \mid X_0 = x)$ only because talking about the probability of $X_0 = x$ might not make sense without saying how the Markov chain is initialized, but in spirit it is a lot like that conditional probability.)

In this equation, we can think of $P_x(X_{m+n}=z)$ as the probability of going from $x$ to $z$ in $m+n$ steps. On the right, $P_x(X_m=y) P_y(X_n = z)$ is the probability of going from $x$ to $y$ in $m$ steps times the probability of going from $y$ to $z$ in $n$ steps, so it is the probability of going from $x$ to $z$ in $m+n$ steps such that the $n^{\text{th}}$ step goes through $y$. By summing over all $y$, we get the left-hand side.

Comment: $P_x$ means $X_0 \equiv x$. Then, $\mu = \delta_x$. Is my unerstanding accurate?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thank you very much!